# How to get checkbox state in Ember.js?

Tags: templates, ember.js, checkbox, components

I have created a **component** which renders checkboxes with values correctly set. They can also respond to click events, so in the hbs template there's a loop which renders the checkboxes like that:

```
<input class="conditions" type="checkbox" value="{{c.id}}" 
  {{action "conditionChecked" r preventDefault=false}} 
  checked={{c.checked}} />{{c.name}}
```

In the component I have the `actions:` that contains the conditionChecked hook. The hook has `c` parameter which is what I'm passing from the template which also has the `checked` attribute that's always equals to `true`.

**How can I access the actual state of the checkbox based on user's selection (checked/unchecked)?**

**EDIT**: I'm a complete newbie in Ember.js. If you could provide a link to an example it would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, first and foremost I would recommend that you use the Ember `{{input type="checkbox" checked=someControllerProperty}}`. This will bind the checked value as a boolean to whatever controller property you pass to the `input` helper's `checked` attribute. No need for all the actions. And it's Ember, there's two way binding, so passing a true value to this helper will render a checkbox with a check mark present.

If you must go down the road you are going (it seems like you're fighting the framework), in your `conditionChecked` action, you can use the handy dandy view helper jquery selector function `this.$()` and find your checkbox. Once found, observe its checked property, and set some value. I gotta say, you're reinventing the wheel here though because this is exactly what the built in `input type="checkbox"` helper does

Comment: But if I need to collect all of the checkboxes' values and compose a single array (eventually it's a stored JSON field in Postres on the server side) how can I bind a checkbox to a single property?

Comment: you could have an array of booleans and `{{#each b in booleanArray}} {{input type="checkbox" checked=b}}{{/each}}`